# How to add icon in kendo UI Angular TabStrip Title?

Tags: icons, font-awesome, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-tabstrip

How to add any type of icon classes (e.g font awesome icons) in kendo UI Angular TabStrip title?
Currently tabStrip title is set using [title] property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the `kendoTabTitle` directive to provide a custom template to the tab title. ([Reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/api/TabTitleDirective/))

To work with a custom template, nest the `kendoTabTitle` directive inside the `kendo-tabstrip-tab` tag.

```
<kendo-tabstrip>
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab ...>
        <ng-template kendoTabTitle>
            My Title (even with icons)
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
</kendo-tabstrip
```